# Hazelcast failed to create an ObjectName when using file|http(s) protocol

Tags: hazelcast

after running on this exception using hazelcast 3.6 :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create an ObjectName
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.jmx.HazelcastMBean.setObjectName(HazelcastMBean.java:116)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.jmx.ConnectionManagerMBean.(ConnectionManagerMBean.java:39)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.jmx.InstanceMBean.createMBeans(InstanceMBean.java:74)
>     at com.hazelcast.jmx.InstanceMBean.(InstanceMBean.java:67)    at
>   com.hazelcast.jmx.ManagementService.(ManagementService.java:67)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:160)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:98)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider.getOrCreateInstance(HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java:98)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider.createHazelcastCacheManager(HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java:64)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastServerCachingProvider.createHazelcastCacheManager(HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java:42)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cache.impl.AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager(AbstractHazelcastCachingProvider.java:94)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager(HazelcastCachingProvider.java:131)

I took look at this part of the code, which is causing the error, on File: HazelcastServerCachingProvider.java (starting at line: 78 ):

```
String location = properties.getProperty(HazelcastCachingProvider.HAZELCAST_CONFIG_LOCATION);
// If config location is specified, get instance through it.
if (location != null) {
    URI uri = new URI(location);
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    if (scheme == null) {
            // It is a place holder
            uri = new URI(System.getProperty(uri.getRawSchemeSpecificPart()));
    }
    ClassLoader theClassLoader = classLoader == null ? getDefaultClassLoader() : classLoader;
    final URL configURL;
    if ("classpath".equals(scheme)) {
            configURL = theClassLoader.getResource(uri.getRawSchemeSpecificPart());
    } else if ("file".equals(scheme) || "http".equals(scheme) || "https".equals(scheme)) {
            configURL = uri.toURL();
    } else {
            throw new URISyntaxException(location, "Unsupported protocol in configuration location URL");
    }
    try {
            Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder(configURL).build();
            config.setClassLoader(theClassLoader);

            **HERE BAD INSTANCENAME IS GENERATED**
            config.setInstanceName(configURL.toString());
            return HazelcastInstanceFactory.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw ExceptionUtil.rethrow(e);
    }
}
```

When using file or http(s) protocol in the passed hazelcast_config_location, we are going to fail creating the mbean, since the hazelCastInstanceName should not contain the character ‘:’, which is unfortunately part of the configURI name.

Is this a Bug or do I overlooked something??

Thanks for your response

Comment: Hi again, this issue is tracked here: [#7548](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7548)

Comment: Hi, seems that it is caused by unquoted name property by instance name in `ConnectionManagerMBean`. We will fix it ASAP. Thanks for reporting the issue.

Answer (score 2):

javax `ObjectName` class does not support the character `:` and throws a `MalformedObjectNameException`. Hazelcast processes this exception and throws `IllegalArgumentException` with the message comes from it.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/jmx/HazelcastMBean.java#L121

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html

Edit: `quote` function should've handled it in your case however, there is a bug in hz apparently. See: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/jmx/ConnectionManagerMBean.java#L38

Comment: Hi Murat, I thing it should also be possible to pass the InstanceName through the properties used to initialize the CacheManager, as it is done when no property for **'hazelcast.location.name'** is given.

Comment: Hey @questioner, both issues are fixed in 3.6.1. As of now, you can use `:` in the instance name without causing a JMX exception. Also, if you set instance name in config (`<instance-name>`), or add `HazelcastCachingProvider.HAZELCAST_INSTANCE_NAME` property in the properties file where you set the config location, it will be used instead of uri.